# Problems with CFZIP on ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfzip

My company recently migrated from Coldfusion 9 to Coldfusion 11. One problem I haven't been able to resolve from this migration is to do with the the way CFZIP works.

In the old server we had a place in our app where we could upload zip files with images and then Coldfusion would unzip them and place them on the server.

```
<!--- Upload the zip --->
<cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="vchrZip"
destination="#app_sysfilepath_site#images\somefolder\zip\"
nameconflict="makeunique">

<!--- Create a directory for our images --->
<cfset folder = Mid(file.serverfile, 1, Len(file.serverfile) - 4)>
<cfdirectory action="create" directory="#app_sysfilepath_site#images\somefolder\#folder#">

<!--- Unzip the zip file and place the contents to the directory--->
<cfzip action="unzip"
file="#app_sysfilepath_site#images\somefolder\zip\#file.serverfile#"
destination="#app_sysfilepath_site#images\somefolder\#folder#"
storepath="false">
```

On coldfusion 9, this would upload the image files to the root of #app_sysfilepath_site#images\somefolder#folder#"

```
#app_sysfilepath_site#images\somefolder\#folder#"
----> Image.png
----> Image2.png
----> Image3.png
```

On Coldfusion 11, this is putting a subfolder with the same name as the zip file with the images inside of it.

```
#app_sysfilepath_site#images\somefolder\#folder#"
---->#folder#
    ----> Image.png
    ----> Image2.png
    ----> Image3.png
```

I tried changing the storepath to 'no', but that didn't work.

Comment: Hmmmm ... did you check the bug tracker? That seems like an outright bug. I checked the CF docs for CF 11 and they are pretty similar to cf 9. I don't see an additional attribute that might do this.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to file a bug report with Adobe.

Comment: I created a work around, but it wasn't pretty. I had to use CFFILE to move each file to the appropiate folder afterwords.

Comment: ick. I would make sure and _check_ the bug list first. Seems like a significant enough issue that others would have stumbled onto it.

Comment: @JackPilowsky If you unzip the file in another directory does it also include the parent folder of the other directory?

Comment: @JackPilowsky If you have a workaround you should add it as an answer

Comment: The workaround was to loop through the contents of the directory and then use <cffile action="move"> from the child folder to the parent folder

Comment: This might be fixed in Update 3: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=selectBug&CFGRIDKEY=3795400

Comment: Yes it was a bug and has been fixed in CF 11 update 3.

Comment: Jack could you post the workaround as an *answer*, so it is more visible (and to close out this thread)?